# How do I set the size of a SF Symbol in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, sf-symbols

How do I set the size of a SF Symbol in Xcode 11 using SwiftUI?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

SF Symbols are similar to fonts, thus:

```
.font(.system(size: 60))
```

Comment: Interesting. Very counter-intuitive since SF Symbols are used inside `Image`

Comment: Not really, especially when you think about web dev and font awesomes

Comment: @Zain I agree with. Not just counter intuitive but weird

Comment: The top answer should include the tip from @mathias-bak about being able to use `.imageScale(Image.Scale)`.

Answer (score 107):

An alternative is to use `.imageScale()`.

```
Image(systemName: "chevron.left").imageScale(.small)
Image(systemName: "chevron.left").imageScale(.medium)
Image(systemName: "chevron.left").imageScale(.large)
```

Comment: These seems to be the recommended way to apply scaling. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10207/

Answer (score 82):

You can set weights and sizes:

```
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .ultraLight))
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .thin))
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular))
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy))
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .black))
```

Answer (score 33):

If you want to use frame you can as well:

```swift
Image(systemName: "plus")
     .resizable()
     .scaledToFit()
     .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
```

Comment: This actually sets the exact size, unlike font approach. Good.

Answer (score 5):

Since iconographic [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/) are deeply integrated into the San Francisco system font (at the moment, we have 4000+ of them), they can be edited using vector graphics tools and can be manipulated habitual way.

```
var body: some View {
    
    Image(systemName: "swift").imageScale(.large)
    
    HStack {
        // Spacer()            
        Label("Swift", systemImage: "swift").scaleEffect(2)       
        // Spacer()
        Text("Swift \(Image(systemName: "swift"))").font(.largeTitle) 
        // Spacer()
    }
}
```

[image]