# How to create Status Bar icon and menu in macOS using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

What is SwiftUI API for creating status bar menus?

Apple seems to use SwiftUI views in Battery & WiFi menus according to the accessibility inspector. Screenshot of a battery menu attached, also its view hierarchy.

[image: Battery menu screenshot]
[image: View hierarchy of the battery menu]

**EDIT:**

Posted the solution as a separate answer.

Comment: Could you clarify where exactly in the AppDelegate this code goes? I'm getting crashes and status bar icons that work temporarily, but disappear quickly.

Comment: Where does it crash exactly? Here "NSStatusBar.system"?

Comment: Yep -- I solved it though. I misunderstood your answer and thought the NSStatusBar was something already created and provided by the system.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*Since this question received more attention lately, and the only reply doesn't fully solve the issue I would like to repeat the edited part of my question and mark it as resolved.*

*Edit2: Added an additional piece of code that allows using a SwiftUI view as the status bar icon. Might be handy for displaying dynamic badges.*

Found a way to show this in [swiftui](/questions/tagged/swiftui) without an annoying `NSPopover`. Even though I used AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` to execute the code, it can be called from any place of your app, even in a SwiftUI lifecycle app.

Here is the code:

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // SwiftUI content view & a hosting view
        // Don't forget to set the frame, otherwise it won't be shown.
        //
        let contentViewSwiftUI = VStack {
            Color.blue
            Text("Test Text")
            Color.white
        }
        let contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentViewSwiftUI)
        contentView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        
        // Status bar icon SwiftUI view & a hosting view.
        //
        let iconSwiftUI = ZStack(alignment:.center) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .padding(2)
                
            Text("3")
                .background(
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                )
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity,  alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                .padding(.trailing, 5)
        }
        let iconView = NSHostingView(rootView: iconSwiftUI)
        iconView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 22)
        
        // Creating a menu item & the menu to add them later into the status bar
        //
        let menuItem = NSMenuItem()
        menuItem.view = contentView
        let menu = NSMenu()
        menu.addItem(menuItem)
        
        // Adding content view to the status bar
        //
        let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        statusItem.menu = menu
        
        // Adding the status bar icon
        //
        statusItem.button?.addSubview(iconView)
        statusItem.button?.frame = iconView.frame

        // StatusItem is stored as a property.
        self.statusItem = statusItem
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! Exactly what I was looking for. However, I can't figure out how to get any interactive elements in the view (buttons, TextFields) to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @BradG. If you add a button to the content view it's interactable. In my case it prints data https://gist.github.com/kmalyshev/7ef834efaeed83014f6ba851582fca0d . Is there anything that blocks interaction in your case?

Comment: You're right, buttons do work. TextFields don't, though. I also have a Menu in the view that isn't working either.

Comment: I created a minimal project to demonstrate. The TextField actually does work initially, but at some point stops accepting new input (typing anything in it closes the menu). Menu never works. https://github.com/bgreenlee/MinimalMenuBarApp

Comment: @BradG.
Unfortunately I didn't got that far. Having some custom view was sufficient for me. There is a documentation on that topic. It says about limitations of such an approach. Perhaps there is a way to overcome limitations, handle mouse and keyboard events manually.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ViewsInMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005166-SW1

Comment: Hey @Ruzard, thanks for the answer, can we update the icon like Telegram did in macOS client, for example there are envelope icon, but when notification has arrived , icon will be changed with number of notifications?

Comment: @eemrah These badges are usually rendered manually, there are examples on stackoverflow how to draw them with UIKit. However the same approach with a HostingView can be used for the icon. I updated the code, please take a look.

Comment: It seems that iconSwiftUI does not sit in the center of statusItem. I have checked with frame. You have added the size and a trailing, are those on purpose?

Answer (score 12):

### `MenuBarExtra` (macOS Ventura)

In macOS 13.0+ and Xcode 14.0+, the [MenuBarExtra](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/MenuBarExtra) struct allows you create a system menu bar, that is similar to NSStatusBar's icons and menus. Use a `MenuBarExtra` when you want to provide access to commonly used functionality, even when your app is not active.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

@available(macOS 13.0, *)                       // macOS Ventura
@main struct StatusBarApp: App {
    
    @State private var command: String = "a"
       
    var body: some Scene {

        MenuBarExtra(command, systemImage: "\(command).circle") {
           
            Button("Uno") { command = "a" }
                .keyboardShortcut("U")
           
            Button("Dos") { command = "b" }
                .keyboardShortcut("D")
           
            Divider()

            Button("Salir") { NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil) }
                .keyboardShortcut("S")
        }
    }
}
```

### Getting rid of the App's icon in the Dock

In Xcode's `Info` tab, choose `Application is agent (UIElement)` and set its value to `YES`.

[image]

Or you can hide App's icon [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70697737/hide-app-icon-from-macos-menubar-on-launch/76068564#76068564).

Comment: Thanks for the update. It took Apple some time to get to the status bar API.
I'd like to add to your reply - it's possible to add any SwiftUI views to 'MenuBarExtra', not just buttons.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to change the size of `systemImage` or `image` in `MenuBarExtra`?

Use the system image, the size is small compare to other icons, such as WiFi or other regular app which has an icon.

Comment: @chunyang.wen, I hope it'll work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342170/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-a-sf-symbol-in-swiftui/73205360#73205360

Comment: @AndyJazz They are not the same. `MenuBarExtra` creates the image itself. We can use `MenuBarExtra(content, label)`. But it seems that it is not working.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menubarextra/init(content:label:)

Not working when I change the size

Comment: Do you have any idea on how we can set a max frame for a `MenuBarExtra` ? I already tried to use the `defaultSize` modifier but it seems that it's not working

Comment: When I use a custom SVG icon, it suffers from scaling issues - it is ugly and pixelated :(

Comment: @jackson89, I have no idea how to set a max frame for it.

Comment: @PavelLobodinský What did you end up doing for MacMenuBarExtra label? It's literally impossible to create a dynamic label without suffering from blurriness, odd scaling and certain views not being rendered at all. I think I'm going to just use the solution below instead of MacMenuBarExtra right now

Comment: @RahulBir I've ended up with the good old NSStatusItem.

Comment: @PavelLobodinský If you don’t mind, could you help me out? I wrote my full app in SwiftUI using the Mac MenuBarExtra, but if I try to use the solution above buttons and text fields don’t seem to work at all.

Comment: @RahulBir Not sure if I can help. I just went through a few online tutorials on how to create a menu bar app. If you open a window/popover on menu-bar-item click, try to call `NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` and `appWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)`.

Comment: I found this blogpost that fixes this issue for me: https://mirzoyan.dev/mirzoyan%20dev%20d62e6ab9344e4ab8a9c14205257ea2cc/Blog%20208f3509a5b74655b973d4dbaaf500e6/Custom%20icon%20for%20SwiftUI%20MenuBarExtra%20fdd31ec3e0af46adb3f7f69129bd6172

Basically it says to use NSImage to initialise an Image as a label. There you can set the ratio on, so it scales properly

Comment: @Ruzard, you can add any SwiftUI view to the MenuBarExtra using the `.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)` modifier on it.

Answer (score 9):

Inside the AppDelegate add the following code:

```
// Create the status item in the Menu bar 
self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(NSStatusItem.variableLength))

// Add a menu and a menu item
let menu = NSMenu()
let editMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
editMenuItem.title = "Edit"
menu.addItem(editMenuItem)

//Set the menu 
self.statusBarItem.menu = menu

//This is the button which appears in the Status bar
if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
    button.title = "Here"
}
```

This will add a Button with a custom Menu to your MenuBar.

[image]

**Edit - How to use SwiftUI View**

As you asked, here is the answer how to use a SwiftUI View.

First create a NSPopover and then wrap your SwiftUI view inside a `NSHostingController`.

```
var popover: NSPopover


let popover = NSPopover()
popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 350, height: 350)
popover.behavior = .transient
popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    self.popover = popover
```

Then instead of showing a NSMenu, toggle the popover:

```
self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(NSStatusItem.variableLength))
if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
     button.title = "Click"
     button.action = #selector(showPopover(_:))
}
```

With following action:

```
@objc func showPopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let button = self.statusBarItem.button
    {
        if self.popover.isShown {
            self.popover.performClose(sender)
        } else {
            self.popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the code you posted is an AppKit way to create those menus. It's not SwiftUI way nor it supports SwiftIUI views.

Comment: Well, if you create a project with AppKit App Delegate Life cycle, you still got an AppDelegate.

Comment: Yes, but it's not what I asked. I am interested in showing swiftUI in that top menu.

Comment: Thank you, the initial version of my question that got eventually blocked for not being direct enough contained a line about NSPopover. That NSPopover seems like a workaround which I wanted to avoid. I really appreciate your response and I will try to give you a bounty the moment I am able to give them. The code you shown definitely will help other people. I'll update my question with more details just in case.

Comment: Happy it helped. I already voted to open it again because that is a really good and helpful question I was searching about aswell

Comment: I added an alternative solution without NSPopover. Perhaps you find it useful too.