# How do you create a Status Bar icon on macOS with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to create an application that starts with a Status Bar icon, and without a application window. It is for a macOS utility that will be invoked from menus displayed from the Status Bar icon.

Can this be done entirely within SwiftUI, or must I use AppKit?

This is what it looks like in AppKit / Cocoa

```
theItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
let theStatusButton = theItem!.button
theStatusButton?.title = "MyApp"
    
let menuItemOne = NSMenuItem(title: "Hey MyApp", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
statusMenu = NSMenu(title: "This to do in MyApp")
statusMenu!.addItem(menuItemOne)
theItem!.menu = statusMenu!
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Everything concerning statusbar item and its menu should be done via NSStatusBar, but if you open some custom view, then that view can be implemented with SwiftUI.

Comment: @Asperi thanks for confirming my suspicion on that. Given this and some of the other requirements that I have, SwiftUI may not be the ideal framework for my application. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

***macOS 13.0+, Xcode 14.0+***

Use SwiftUI's `MenuBarExtra` structure to create a Status Bar icon and menu on macOS Ventura.

```
struct MenuBarExtra<Label, Content> where Label : View, Content : View
```

Look at [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949572/how-to-create-status-bar-icon-menu-with-swiftui-like-in-macos-big-sur/73508868#73508868) for details.