# Hide app icon from macOS menubar on launch

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm making a macOS `MenuBar app` only, so how would you hide the app's icon from the macOS dock when it's launched?

I haven't seen anywhere where this is explained nor found any SwiftUI APIs/interactions with the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the following property in your Info.plist `Application is agent (UIElement)` to `YES`

You can find it in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsuielement).

Or you can manually edit the Info.plist and add the following key:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256)

> *LSUIElement (Boolean - macOS)* specifies whether the app runs as an
> agent app. If this key is set to YES, Launch Services runs the app as
> an agent app. Agent apps do not appear in the Dock or in the Force
> Quit window. Although they typically run as background apps, they can
> come to the foreground to present a user interface if desired. A click
> on a window belonging to an agent app brings that app forward to
> handle events.
>
> The Dock and loginwindow are two apps that run as agent apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide App's icon using Xcode `Info` Tab's parameters. Here's an [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949572/how-to-create-status-bar-icon-and-menu-in-macos-using-swiftui/73508868#73508868) of how to do it.

However, implementing the following code you can hide app's icon in the Dock programmatically.

```
import SwiftUI

@available(macOS 13.0, *) @main struct YourApp : App {
               
    var body: some Scene {
        let _ = NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy(.prohibited)
        
        MenuBarExtra("", systemImage: "apple.logo") {
            Button("Quit") { 
                NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil) 
            }
        }
    } 
}
```