# How to create a dynamic Mac menu bar icon

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Mac menu bar app which I created using MenuBarExtra in SwiftUI. However, the label argument doesn’t work properly for any view that’s not a SFSymbol or text. I can’t even put a custom image without it being oddly resized. In my scenario, I want to create a dynamic menu bar icon kinda like Apple’s battery icon on the mac.

I did see this post [How to create Status Bar icon and menu in macOS using SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949572/how-to-create-status-bar-icon-and-menu-in-macos-using-swiftui), however this solution causes all of the buttons and interactive elements in my menu bar app to stop working. I can’t seem to find anything online and I’ve been trying / reading documentation for the last couple of days.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can display a custom image however you must size it properly and it must be in the Asset catalog