# Enlarged buttons and screen

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am developing a navigation app using Swift UI.
For some reasons, some of the test device have enlarged buttons. They almost looks like they are zoomed in for some reasons.

I cannot replicate this issue using xcode emulator, please help

Correct - This is what suppose to look (pic from iPhone 6s)

[image]

Wrong - Below is from another iPhone 6s (test device from tester)

[image]

Wrong - Below is from beta tester on iPhone 11

[image]

Comment: Yes I am using SF Symbols. Do you mean if they turn on dynamic type, they will have this issue? Is there a way to bypass/ignore this settings on user's device? @mahan

Answer (score 1):

Probably they have changed the font size on their iPhone should your App support dynamic types.

Try changing the font size on your iPhone or ask them if have done so.

Change the font size

> - Go to Settings > Display & Brightness, then select Text Size.
> - Drag the slider to select the font size you want.

Make the font even bigger

> - Go to Settings > Accessibility, then select Display & Text Size.
> - Tap Larger Text for larger font options.
> - Drag the slider to select the font size you want.

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202828)

---

You can set fixed size on the images to disable it.

```
Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").font(.system(size: 20))
```

#### More Info

[How do I set the size of a SF Symbol in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342170/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-a-sf-symbol-in-swiftui)

Comment: Thank you @Mahan, is there a way to bypass/ignore this?